# Image not covering all screen size

Tags: html, css

I have an image applied to the body but it does not cover all the screen sizes.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<body class = "bg" style=" background-image: url(<?= list1[0]; ?>); height: 100%; margin: 0; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
```

How can I make it cover all screen sizes? I am also open to any other option.

Comment: why did I received a negative vote?? Is my question not clear enough or confusing?

Comment: Use instead of percent "vh" and "vw":

`width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;`

Comment: [gorevanova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13513677/gorevanova) maybe both `vw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html { 
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592819005124-1401b90865dd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Other HTML -->
  </body>
</html>
```

For more please read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) on CSS-TRICKS.

Answer (score 3):

This is enough to do the job

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.bg {
    background-image: url("your_image.png");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others answered, you can do that using simple html & css. Here is a shortcut property:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url("url/of/your/image.png") no-repeat cover;
}
```

Here is more information about shortcut [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property and fullscreen [images](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp).

Answer (score 1):

simple use css and type

```css
.bg {
    top:0%;left:0%;width:100%;height:100%;
}
```